# Simultaneous processing in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have been stuck with this problem for about 2 months now. I have 2 different GUI's, one built with Windows Forms and the other is WPF. They each have text boxes that I want to refresh and update every few seconds. I have accomplished this no porblem, however, using both the `$Form.Refresh()` and `textbox.Refresh()` method in loops mean you cannot interact with the rest of the GUI's tabs and buttons as I had to put it into an infinite loop to update the text boxes every few seconds.

I have explored the `start-job` to do the data gathering for the text boxes, but I still get stuck with trying to update the text boxes without looping the script to use the `Receive-Job`.

Can someone tell me how to go about independently updating the cells, while still allowing other interaction with the GUI. Right now I have an external GUI that is stuck in an infinite loop to display the data while the master GUI is free to do the rest of the work and kill the data GUI when completed.

Comment: https://blog.netnerds.net/2016/12/runspaces-simplified/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing I end up doing for infinite loops in GUI is to add this inside the loop.

```
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
```

It is quick and dirty but works. So you can use this in the loop that waits for the `Receive-job`.

On another note, Jobs are not too efficient. Each job creates an individual process and can get messy when you have multiple jobs. If you are running into that, check out PowerShell Runspaces. Best way I know to handle multithreading.